# Add-on not showing up in Blender 2.82

Tags: export, add-on

Today, I downloaded Blender 2.82 and attempted to install an add-on that would allow me to export models in a format compatible with the program MikuMikuDance (MMD for short). After doing my research, I attempted to install the add-on while all the files were in a ZIP folder. However, no matter what I try - changing the add-on directory in the Preferences, getting rid of excess dots in file names - the add-on won't show up even though a message indicates it was successfully installed. I've tried looking at other questions regarding similar issues, but nothing seems to help, and I'm at the end of my rope here.

Comment: Hello :). I'm pretty sure it works with Blender 2.8 [available here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) but perhaps it wasn't updated for 2.82.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have the reputation to comment this: Powroupi's latest version of Blender MMD Tools works through version 2.90 (my version). Download it [here](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools).)

As mentioned by Kisracora, the plugin needs to be unzipped before the **mmd_tools** folder can be inserted into the **addons** folder. (If you're on Windows, you can simply enter the zip folder without unzipping and click-drag the **mmd_tools** folder in.) If doing that and enabling the plugin in Blender DOESN'T get it to show up, you may want to try **rightclick > Properties > Unblock** the zip (checkbox near the bottom of the Properties window).

Answer (score 0):

MMD Tools is confirmed to work in the latest version of Blender, so this is not a version issue. However, make sure to double check you are downloading the 2.8+ version of MMD tools, and not a version for 2.79 and below.

Did you make sure to unzip the file before attempting to install the add-on? MMD Tools contains multiple plug-ins, so you may not be able to use Blender's built-in "Install" button.

Unzip the downloaded folder titled **"blender_mmd_tools-dev_test"**
Inside the unzipped folder, there should be a folder titled **"mmd_tools."** We are going to manually put this in the add-ons folder for our Blender Program.
The image below shows the file path for my add-ons folder.

[image]

Yours will possibly be the same, but it may be different.  If you cannot find it, go to **"This PC"** and search for **"Blender Foundation"** to find the folders.

Drag the folder **"mmd_tools"** into your **"addons"** folder.

Return to Blender. Go to Edit > Preferences > Add-ons and search for "mmd"

MMD tools should be in the list. If it is not, hit refresh and make sure that "Enabled Add-ons Only" is not checked.